# codeigniter - error in my program

Tags: php, codeigniter

i'm following the tutorial on this url:
http://www.codefactorycr.com/login-with-codeigniter-php.html

I'm trying to made some modification to the tutorial:
a login form with 3 input box (company name, username, password)
Below i encounter problem with verifylogin.php
Any guidance is greatly appreciated, thanks.

```
<?php   if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class VerifyLogin extends CI_Controller
{
public function __construct()
{   parent::__construct();
}

public function index()
{
    $config_login = array(
            array(
             'field'   => 'company',
             'label'   => 'Company',
             'rules'   => 'trim|required|min_length[1]|max_length[50]|strip_tags|encode_php_tags|htmlspecialchars|xss_clean'
            ),
            array(
             'field'   => 'username',
             'label'   => 'Username',
             'rules'   => 'trim|required|min_length[1]|max_length[50]|strip_tags|encode_php_tags|htmlspecialchars|xss_clean'
            ),
            array(
             'field'   => 'password',
             'label'   => 'Password',
             'rules'   => 'required|xss_clean|callback__check_database'
            )
    );

    $this -> form_validation -> set_rules($config_login);
```

yes. problem solved aafter i change the $config to $config_login.
Many thanks for your guidance.

Comment: $config is a global variable already set in the "application/config/config.php". Change the name of your variable and you should be fine. Check here for accessing it: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/config.html

Comment: Dominic is right. $config is [reserved variable in CodeIgniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/reserved_names.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change all the where conditions to like this,

```
$this->db->where('company',$company);
$this->db->where('username',$username);
$this->db->where('password',$password);
```

As you are passing these variables to your model function login.
 and change your login as

```
function login($company, $username, $password){
```

Hope this helps

Regards

iijb

Comment: thanks, but it gives error "undefine variables in user model"

Comment: you have to get these variables in your model login function. check my answer again, i have edited